# Acumatica - Require Field in Setup Extension to be Not Null

Tags: acumatica, data-access

I have a setup DAC extension that defines a default value for an SOOrder field. I need this field to not be null before the user can use the Sales Orders form. I know how to accomplish this with a custom setup DAC by using the PXPrimaryGraphAttribute on the DAC, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with a DAC extension. I want to make the Sales Orders form look like this when my custom setup field is null:

[image]

Here is my DAC extension:

```
    public sealed class SOSetupExt : PXCacheExtension<SOSetup>
    {
        [SalesPerson(DisplayName = "Enabled Default Salesperson", Required = true)]
        public int? UsrEnabledDefaultSalesperson { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrEnabledDefaultSalesperson : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrEnabledDefaultSalesperson> { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate the field with a graph extension event handler and throw a `PXSetupNotEnteredException` exception:

```
throw new PXSetupNotEnteredException(ErrorMessages.SetupNotEntered, typeof(SOSetup), typeof(SOSetup).Name);
```

Comment: This throws the error correctly, but how do you make the link navigate to the "Sales Orders Preferences" form? Right now, it navigates back to the "Sales Orders" form when I click on it.

Comment: You can try to instantiate a SOSetupMaint graph and then throw  PXRedirectRequiredException with that graph object in parameter.

Comment: I've tried this method already, but you cannot create a graph instance in an event handler.

Comment: Creating a graph instance should work in this context: PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOSetupMaint>()

Comment: This causes an Acuminator error - *PX1045: A PXGraph instance cannot be created within an event handler*.

Comment: Acuminator is a linter. Those are not compilation error. I don't know what is your exact code and IDE setup but I can tell you that graph created in event handlers is all over Acumatica codebase. Definitely not something that can't be done.

Comment: If it really bothers you, put it in another method..

Comment: Redirecting to a SOSetup DAC object is another possibility. It's also possible to redirect with Screen ID but this is not common. Graph redirection is the most common.